# How to upload image in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, upload

I tried to follow to **manage** image upload from different tutorials but i always get this error that stack overflow can't answer.
So anyone who can help me to upload image in **Laravel** in cloud storage?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: If you can tell uw what the error is, and share your code, we can help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here you can use this code

name('image.upload');

Route::post('image-upload', [ ImageUploadController::class, 'imageUploadPost' ])->name('image.upload.post');

hp

  

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  

class ImageUploadController extends Controller

{

     /**

     * Display a listing of the resource.

     *

     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response

     */

    public function imageUpload()

    {

        return view('imageUpload');

    }

    

    /**

     * Display a listing of the resource.

     *

     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response

     */

    public function imageUploadPost(Request $request)

    {

        $request->validate([

            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',

        ]);

    

        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();  

     

        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

  

        /* Store $imageName name in DATABASE from HERE */

    

        return back()

            ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.')

            ->with('image',$imageName); 

    }

}